# How to import javascript resource into thymeleaf template without Spring?

Tags: java, import, resources, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf WITHOUT Spring. Configuration looks

```
@WebListener
public class ThymeleafConfig implements ServletContextListener {

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    TemplateEngine engine = templateEngine(sce.getServletContext());
    TemplateEngineUtil.storeTemplateEngine(sce.getServletContext(), engine);
}

private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ServletContext servletContext) {
    TemplateEngine engine = new TemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver(servletContext));
    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver(ServletContext servletContext) {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}
```

where I specify path */src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates* as prefix */WEB-INF/templates/* for my *index.html* template. It works. Now I am trying to add javascrpt static resource that is located at */src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/js*, so that I can import it in template, like

```
<script src="example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

OR

```
<script th:src="@{/example.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I add javascript resource? All documentation and examples I have found are for the combination Spring+thymeleaf.

EDIT:
The project was configured incorrectly, maven plugin *maven-resources-plugin* was missing. Thus resources were not recognized.

Comment: so, you initialize the Thymeleaf TemplateEngine. but where's the actual problem? what exactly is not working for you? if you write this `script src..` line into `index.html` template, is it rendered into file?

Comment: @62mkv The root of my problem is I dont know default location where to put javascript file for the template to recognize it. All combinations I tried I get *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'* which is issue of file location.

Comment: so do you want to have .js file as a _template_ or you just want to serve plain javascript file? in the question you only provide an html template snippet.

Comment: Static, public, resources are typically in `src/main/resources/js`, `src/main/resources/css`, and so on - but it can depend on the web container you are using (and how the container is configured). Assuming that location, then you use `<script src="/js/example.js"></script>` to reference your JS file in the `<head>` of your HTML page. This is all completely independent of Thymeleaf. On the other hand, `WEB-INF` is not publicly accessible - so it is appropriate that your (private!) templates are in there.